# Is there a way to Clone one or many Entities (records) in Code

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

NOTE: at this time I am stuck on 2sxc v9.43.2 on this project.

After selecting a set of records from my Content Type, I need to be able to duplicate them changing 1 of the fields along the way. Here is my almost-working idea so far. The use case is simple, they have Programs that people can register for. They change each Season, but only a little (prices, dates/times, etc). And they need the Current Season live and unchanged while they edit the Next Season. So we are still in the fall season (EntityId 1732) with 97 active programs. We want to click a button and clone all 97 programs as is, but IN TO the new Next Season (1735 below).

Two questions:

1. if this way works, what syntax would work on ent/Attributes to delivery the "object" as needed in the `fields.Add()` line
2. is there another 2sxc way to do this? Some other variant of the App.Data.Create() method or some other method in the API? I just need to duplicate the record with 1 field (Season) changed?
3. is there a better way to do this in the latest versions of 2sxc, v11.7+ ?

```
    // we are going to duplicate the current Season's programs in to the new season
    // cheating for now, pre-made new 1735 in Seasons, current is 1732
    var programs = AsDynamic(App.Data["Programs"])
      .Where(p => ((List<DynamicEntity>)p.Season).First().EntityId == selectedSeason.EntityId);
    // @programs.Count() // 97
    foreach(var copy in programs)
    {
      var fields = new Dictionary<string, object>();
      var ent = AsEntity(copy);
      foreach(var attr in ent.Attributes)
      {
        if(attr.Key == "Season")
        {
          fields.Add(attr.Key, new List<int> { 1735 });
        }
        else
        {
          fields.Add(attr.Key, ent.GetBestValue(attr.Key));   // object??
        }
      }
      App.Data.Create("Programs", fields);
    }
```

Comment: Is this still an issue? I would love to help but have been away from SO for a month so I don't want to invest time on issues that are already closed.

Comment: Yes, still open, not able to resolve. Tried many different spins and syntax, but not able to Create() without throwing an error. I still need a way in code to clone an existing entity. And update it before creating it, or after with an update. Seems like there should be something easy somewhere in the API, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 3 ways to clone

1. Simple way using edit-ui
2. hard way using c# / server api
3. Semi-hard way using REST api

The simple way is to use the edit ui. You can see an example in the replace-dialog, there is a copy button there. This would open the edit UI with an existing item, but tell it it's a copy, so on save it would create a new one.

Combine this with a prefill or something and I think you would be good to go.

The second way is using the App.Data.Create - your code looks fairly good. I assume it also works and you were just wondering if there was a 1-liner - or am I mistaken?

The last way is using JS REST. Basically write some JS that gets an item, changes the object (resets the id) and posts it back to the endpoint for saving.

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem, but thats a lot of options and I can make them work for the client. My main issue is with Create() with entity and hyperlink field types. I either get null reference exceptions or the copied Entity is not quite the same. I saw you answered a similar Q about hyperlink fields, I'll review that and give it another run thought. Did you read my use-case? I find it odd that you think the UI is a possible solution. ;)

Comment: For hyperlink fields I guess your problem is that when you read it, you get the link instead of the stored "file:72". I have two suggstions: without upgrade: do `AsEntity(original).GetBestValue<string>("name-of-link-field")` or with upgrade (11.11) there is a new command on dynamic entity `original.Get("name-of-link-field", convertLinks: false)` see also https://docs.2sxc.org/api/dot-net/ToSic.Sxc.Data.IDynamicEntity.html#ToSic_Sxc_Data_IDynamicEntity_Get_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_

Comment: finally getting back to this since the client is expecting to add the new seasons again soon. I did get everything working, I believe I have all the field types copying in their data correct to the new one. However, I am doing everything by attribute.Key... I could greatly simplify and re-use this if I could instead get the entity's field type. So I want something like `if(AsEntity(original).FieldType == "HyperLink") { do this stuff}`. I have explored the API docs but have not spotted how to get to the info. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled upon situation where I needed to create entity and set its field value, which has type of another entity. If that's your question #1, you need to add there `EntityGuid`.
`fields.Add(attr.Key, attr.EntityGuid);`. That should bind one entity to another one.
And no, I didn't stumble upon better way to copy entity then just to create a new one. At least so far.